# how to implement the ERC20 token transferFrom method in solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity

Assuming I have a wallet, I want to authorize another wallet to send a transfer on my behalf, how do I implement the above using the following practice.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import 'Token.sol';

contract TransferToken{
    function transferFrom(address recipient, uint amount) external {
        Token token = Token(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F3555);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    }
}

contract Owner {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external {
        Token token = Token(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138);
        token.approve(0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465E7f2, amount);
    
        TransferToken transferToken = TransferToken(0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465E7f2);
        transferToken.transferFrom(recipient, amount);
    }
}
```

In the above example, i am using the openZappelin implementation for ERC20 on the import (Token.sol) now my question is this ... since I want to use a real wallet with ERC20 token how do I implement the above example, I am thinking for this I don't need the import anymore, but I don't know how to implement it without too many mistakes already, I am very new to solidity and I am using remix for the above implementation

will be glad if i could get a help on this

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "path/to/openzeppelin/contracts/token/IERC20.sol";

contract Owner {

    function safeTransferFrom(address token, address from, address to, uint256 amount) external return bool{
            IERC20 token = IERC20(token);
            if(token.allowance(from, to) < amount){
                revert("You don't have allowance for that")
            }
            token.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
            return true;
    }
}
```

But you can manage this dealing directly with the ERC20 contract. You can call `approve(to, amount)` and then call `safeTransferFrom(from, to, amount` with a second wallet using you library and language of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am not sure how to implement this, my understanding about this is very low, i am trying to get a full understanding about this by implementing this using a token in my wallet, but there is a gap in my understanding of this method, i know it's not okay to ask for a help on a complete code to implement this, but i will glad if you can expand my understanding with a complete example i can work with thanks in advance

Comment: Then you need to do some steps backs and learn the foundation of solidity and web3. Maybe a udemy course.

Comment: Thanks for the help